# C++ Method won't call correct information from variable

Tags: c++, variables

I am working a a text adventure and have come across an error when I try to call a method from another method. The method returns the private int player_health and private int `player_attack` this work when I call it in main but when I call it in my `combat_handler` class it just give me a random number. I call it the exact same way in both class. Here is my code

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "player_handler.h"
#include "enemy_handler.h"
#include "combat_handler.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    player_handler phobj;
    enemy_handler ehobj;
    combat_handler cbobj;
    phobj.test_player_systems();
    ehobj.test_enemy_stats();
    cbobj.player_turn();
    phobj.get_player_stats();

    return 0;
}
```

`player_handler` header

```
#ifndef PLAYER_HANDLER_H
#define PLAYER_HANDLER_H


class player_handler
{
    public:
        player_handler();
        int get_player_health();
        int get_player_attack();
        void get_player_stats();
        void add_player_health(int x);
        void remove_player_health(int x);
        void add_player_attack(int y);
        void set_player_stats(int x, int y);
        int test_player_systems();
    private:
        int player_health;
        int player_attack;
};

#endif // PLAYER_HANDLER_H
```

**player_handler.cpp**

```
#include "player_handler.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

player_handler::player_handler()
{
    //cout << "working"<< endl;
}

    //Getting the players stats
    int player_handler::get_player_health()
    {
        return player_health;
    }
    int player_handler::get_player_attack()
    {
        return player_attack;
    }
    void player_handler::get_player_stats()
    {
        cout << "the players health is " << get_player_health()<<endl;
        cout << "The players attack is " << get_player_attack() <<endl;
    }

    //setting the player stats
    void player_handler::set_player_stats(int x, int y)
    {
        player_handler::player_health = x;
        player_attack = y;
        //cout << "player health is " << player_health << endl;
        //cout << "player attack is " << player_attack << endl;
    }

    //Player health control
    void player_handler::add_player_health(int x)
    {
        //cout << "The old player health was " << player_health << endl;
        player_health = player_health + x;
        //cout << "Your health is now " << player_health << endl;
    }

    void player_handler::remove_player_health(int x)
    {
        //cout << "you lost " << x << " health" << endl;
        player_health = player_health - x;
        //cout << "Your new health is " << player_health << endl;
    }

    //player  attack control
    void player_handler::add_player_attack(int y)
    {
        //cout << "Your attack has been upgraded by " << y << " points" << endl;
        player_attack = player_attack+y;
        //cout << "You attack is now " << player_attack <<endl;
    }

    //test all player systems
    int player_handler::test_player_systems()
    {

        set_player_stats(10,10);
        cout <<"The player health is " << get_player_health()<<endl;
        cout <<"the player attack is " << get_player_attack() << endl;
        add_player_health(5);
        remove_player_health(5);
        add_player_attack(5);
        get_player_stats();

        return 0;
    }
```

Now  keep in mind that all this works it returns the right value for `player_health` and `player_attack`. now here is my problem it just gives me a random number

**combat_handler** header

```
#ifndef COMBAT_HANDLER_H
#define COMBAT_HANDLER_H



class combat_handler
{
    public:
        combat_handler();
        int player_turn();
        int enemy_turn();
    private:
        int player_input;
        int player_dmg_given;
        int enemy_dmg_given;
};

#endif // COMBAT_HANDLER_H
```

**combat_handler.cpp**

```
#include "combat_handler.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "player_handler.h"



using namespace std;

combat_handler::combat_handler()
{
    cout << "combat handler on-line\n";
}
    int combat_handler::player_turn()
    {
        player_handler phobj;
        cout <<  "Would you like to (1)check stats (2) Enter the room?\n";
        cin >> player_input;
        switch(player_input){
        case 1:
            cout << "one"<<endl;
            phobj.get_player_stats();
            break;
        default:
            cout << "entering the room.\n";
            break;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

The error happens when I call get_player_stats from the `phobj` in the combat handler class.

Comment: `phobj` in `player_turn()` is not the same player as in `main()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
player_handler phobj;
```

This would call default constructor for `player_handler`( from your code it seems you are doing nothing in default constructor). And then you are calling `get_player_stats()` without setting the values. So, it would surely give you random values.

Earlier in main,

```
phobj.test_player_systems();  <<<< This is setting values.
phobj.get_player_stats();     <<<< Then you are querying on values already set.
```